# C++ equivalent for C-style assertions?

Tags: c++, assertion

`assert()` is very useful for debugging; they ensure pre and post conditions are met.
However, they are mostly based on macros and other preprocessor magic to ensure they are either erased from release builds (which is important to me) or because the assertion can be directly printed : `assert(x > y)` would print `assertion failed : x > y` for example, which is not possible if it is a simple function because `x > y` would be a bool that prints `true` or `false`.
Now to my actual question:
Is there an equivalent for `assert()` that does **NOT** rely on preprocessor/macro and ensures the assertions are removed from production build?

```
inline void assertion(const bool& expr,const char* msg) {
    if constexpr (DebugBuild) {
        if (!expr) throw std::runtime_error(msg);
    }
};
```

`assertion(x > y , "x must be greater than y!");`

this code snippet removes the inner `if` in Non-debug builds, but the function is still called in production build since the expression is still evaluated.

Edit:

Here is a code snippet:
https://godbolt.org/z/PWso7f

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
constexpr bool DebugMode = false;
void assertion(const bool& expr, const std::string& msg) {
    if constexpr (DebugMode) {
        if(!expr) throw std::runtime_error(msg);
    }
}
int main(void) {
    int i = 1;
    assertion(i > 2,"number must be greater than 1!");
    return 0;
}
```

I would it to expect to compile in a simple return statement in `main`.

Comment: You might be looking for `static_assert`, however the semantics of that are "slightly" different.

Comment: `if constexpr` really only works with templates.  Outside of a template the if statement is not discarded.

Comment: I know about `static_assert` but it only asserts during compile time, not during runtime, as far as i know.

Comment: A good compiler will optimize function calls away that don’t do anything.

Comment: That is correct. So, your basic options is to place your bets that your compiler will be smart enough to completely optimize away a call to this inline function when it does not do anything.

Comment: @t.niese checked with Compiler Explorer and thats not the case for gcc, clang and msvc

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It can't be optimized away if the expression has possible side effects. Although you probably shouldn't use expressions with side effects in `assert()`, either.

Comment: `assertion(foo());` without visible definition of `foo` would have to call `foo`... [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7WYsn5)

Comment: @Raildex can you show an example in compiler explorer where this is not the case. For this [simple example](https://godbolt.org/z/Pj8769) it is optimized away.

Comment: @t.niese oh, the flags where missing on my end. I apologize!

Comment: @barmar - if the first thing that the function does is `if constexpr`, and that evaluates to false, and nothing else happens in the function, it is logically impossible for the function to have any side effects. If it does, you should report it as a compiler bug.

Comment: @t.niese wait nvm. take a look here: https://godbolt.org/z/ha68M3

Comment: I'm talking about a side effect in the function argument. Arguments are evaluated before the function is called. @SamVarshavchik  E.g. `assertion(a++, "Message");`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Never mind, I see what you're saying. That would be optimized to just `a++;` and not call the function. But C-style assert will not even execute `a++;`

Comment: If that's the case, then there would be a difference in behavior even in the macro-based implementation of `assert()`, @barmar, so it's fairly obvious that this is not the case.

Comment: @Raildex first of all you have `const bool DebugBuild = true;`, and you changed `const char *` to `const std::string&  msg`, with that change  `assertion(x > y , "x must be greater than y!");` has to construct a `std::string`.

Comment: @t.niese I see so using `const char*` actually works. thank you!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1a0bfa00f23bac1) of different behavior with side effect in `assert`.

Comment: @Jarod42 having an expression that has side effects in an `assert` might be a bad idea anyway.

Comment: @t.niese: Agreed, but `assertion(expensive_check())` would still be problematic in release... So I think we cannot replace MACRO here.<, unless we change prototype to  take callable instead of boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get rid of MACRO at zero-cost.

You might have:

```
template <typename Func, bool Debug = DebugBuild>
void assertion(Func&& f, const char* msg) {
    if constexpr (Debug) {
        if (!f()) throw std::runtime_error(msg);
    }
};
```

With (more verbose) usage:

```
bool expensive_check(int);
int main() {
    int i = 1;
    assertion([i](){ return i > 2;}, "number must be greater than 2!");
    assertion([i](){ return expensive_check(i);}, "number doesn't respect check!");
}
```

to avoid possible expensive computation of parameter (Similar thing can be done for message string)

I would expect than optimization would get rid of function calls, but "symbols" (C-string, lambda) would probably be present in executable...